# Relationship action on custom user profile in custom block

Tags: 7, blocks, panels, users

I have customized the user profile view using panels. All great. Works like a charm. However i am stuck at one point. In the default view there is an option for users to add relationships (using the user relationship module). Now i want that the relationship action, i.e, Follow UserName should appear in my custom block. SO is there any way i can get the relationship action (only the action) to be displayed in a custom block.

Regards

PS: This seemed relevant: http://drupal.org/node/560402 Using this page i tried :

```
<?php
global $user;
$account = user_load(arg(1));
$actions = _user_relationships_ui_actions_between($user, $account);
if (count($actions)) {
  print theme('item_list', $actions);
}
?>
```

as well as

```
<?php
global $user;
$account = user_load($node->uid);
$actions = _user_relationships_ui_actions_between($user, $account);
if (count($actions)) {
  print theme('item_list', $actions);
}
?>
```

and different other code samples given in http://drupal.org/node/560402...however now when i click on user, it leads me to The White Screen of Death. What am i missing